# Help with Anita Graser's guide on making tapered rivers. River shapefile has "width" field but expression is not working

Tags: qgis, line, geometry, rivers

https://anitagraser.com/2017/04/17/better-river-styles-with-tapered-lines/

**This is her expression**

```
CASE 
WHEN "GEW_GRKL" = '< 10 km2 Fluss' THEN 0.2
WHEN "GEW_GRKL" = '10 km2 Fluss' THEN 0.4
WHEN "GEW_GRKL" = '100 km2 Fluss' THEN 0.6
WHEN "GEW_GRKL" = '1.000 km2 Fluss' THEN 0.8
ELSE 1.0
END 
* ( 1- ( @geometry_part_num /  @geometry_part_count ))
```

I copied it and replaced the field but it didn't work so I modified the expression a bit. The width of the river shapefille includes 0-8, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 35, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100, 200, 500.

**Test expression** which isn't working even with the `km2` and `Fluss`

```
CASE 
WHEN "width" = '500' THEN 2.0
ELSE 1.0
END 
* ( 1- ( @geometry_part_num /  @geometry_part_count ))
```

This is the attributes of the river shapefile
[image]

How do I make my expression work?

Comment: Please add information on your attributes, as well as compare it with the data by used by Mrs. Graser.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Ok. I'll remove the first question. Thanks Erik and PolyGeo.

Answer (score 3):

```
'< 10 km2 Fluss'
```

Is what is stored in Anita's attribute table. It is a string field describing the flow rate of the river.

If your width field is not a string, rather a number, then you need to use numbers instead of strings.

Try:

```
CASE 
WHEN "width" > 499 THEN 2.0
ELSE 1.0
END 
* ( 1- ( @geometry_part_num /  @geometry_part_count ))
```